# How to help our 2.5-year-old daughter deal with an abusive 5-year-old boy?

Tags: toddler, daycare, bullying

In the Kindergaden, our 2.5-year-old daughter has periodic confrontations with a 5-year-old boy, who used to hit her on the head with a toy. She is totally scared of him up to not willing to go to the Kindergarden.

What are modalities before changing Kindergarden - try to explain something to her she should e.g. shout aloud for help, or talk to parents? How not to let her alone with this? How much is to protect and how much to learn to react properly? In general she is full of courage, so not a fearful kid.

Comment: You said nothing about whoever is in charge at your kindergarten, or who supervises the kids (apparently not as well as you'd like).  That would seem to me to be an important first step.

Comment: You have a 2.5 year old in kindergarten, in the same class as five year olds?  Or is this a language issue - use of the term "pre-school" vs. "kindergarten"

Comment: All ages 1.5-preschool together

Answer (score 9):

No 2.5 year old should have to deal with a bully, even to the extent of calling for help. If this is happening regularly then the kindergarten is failing to supervise the children properly. If at all possible you should move your daughter somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Talk to the teachers. They need be supervising this boy more closely to manage this behaviour. Possibly shadowing him for a while if need be. It is part of their job. Ask what they are doing , if they are aware etc. they may be doing more already than you realise to help. Talking to them is important.

Your daughter meanwhile could simply be told to avoid this boy and not to play with him, tell him to ‘stop’ in a firm tone. Also to tell a teacher if she needs help.